# Construct URL query from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

Taking a pandas dataframe of the form:

```
fname lname age
mark  trumb 34
samb  jones 26
```

I'd like to construct a url query using the requests module.
Normally, I would construct the url like so:

```
payload = {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application'}
base_url = 'https://website.com/'
req = requests.post(base_url,headers=headers,params=payload)
```

How would I best use this so that the dataframe columns become the keys, and the rows become the values?

The new output column (req) would look like this:

```
fname lname age req
mark  trumb 34  https://website.com?fname=mark&lname=trumb&age=34
samb  jones 26  https://website.com?fname=samb&lname=jones&age=26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build it like this:

```
In [46]:
df['req'] = 'https://website.com?' + 'fname=' + df['fname'] + '&lname=' + df['lname'] + '&age=' + df['age'].astype(str)
df

Out[46]:
  fname  lname  age                                                req
0  mark  trumb   34  https://website.com?fname=mark&lname=trumb&age=34
1  samb  jones   26  https://website.com?fname=samb&lname=jones&age=26
```

A dynamic method can be done by joining the column names with the values:

```
In [106]:
def func(x):
    tuple_list = list(zip('&' + x.index + '=', x.astype(str)))
    return ''.join([''.join(item) for item in tuple_list])

df['req'] = r'https://website.com?' + df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
df['req']

Out[106]:
0    https://website.com?&name=mark&lname=trumb&age=34
1    https://website.com?&name=samb&lname=jones&age=26
Name: req, dtype: object
```

Comment: yes - however, I should have said that I want to apply the new series the requests.post method, in order to practice passing functions to series items.. for instance, I could have 100 columns that I would not want to write out.